# Separable extension embedding

Tags: field-theory

Prove that there exists a maximal separable extension $k^{sep}$ of a field $k$.
That is every element of $k^{sep}$ is separable over $k$ and every extention of $k$ having this property embeds in $k^{seop}$ as an intermediate extension.